# NPM start "Lite-Server" - how do I serve my index.cshtml file to the browser?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, visual-studio-code

trying to learn how to use Visual Studio Code and specifically how to run/compile my project.  I set up a project in visual studio and using the F5 start I am able to run my project.  I am now working in my project using Visual Studio Code and struggling with how I serve it to the browser using "Lite-Server". I am able to to start my server using 'npm start' and can navigate to see to my static .css and .json files but I cannot figure out how to serve the html to the browser.

Here is the scripts section in my package.json which seems to run okay and I get no errors when I run "npm start"

```
"scripts": {
"start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
"tsc": "tsc",
"tsc:w": "tsc -w",
"lite": "lite-server",
"typings": "typings",
"postinstall": "typings install"
},
```

When I start my server I just get "Cannot GET /Home/Index" So I think there is an issue with my routing.  I have tried navigating to my Index file in just about every way I can think that makes sense.

My routeconfig.cs file contains this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

[image]

Here is a screenshot of what my project looks like.  I feel like I am simply browsing to the wrong location since I can run my project using regular visual studio and everything works but I am completely lost using this IDE.

Any help is appreciated or an explanation of what I am doing wrong. The project is using ASP.NET MVC and Angular 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lite-server` is a node server module , and it serves HTML and wont be able to handle `.cshtml` which is resolved by razor engine, you probably have to use MSBuild only for your application, and serve pages using IIS only.However you can create gulp tasks or if using Angular CLI use that to build your client side code.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes this helps, I did not understand I could not use lite-server.  I was able to get this working by installing an extension in visual studio code that allowed me to run IIS express and now everything works.

Comment: Gulp and BrowserSync work well on multiple networked devices and computers.